# Node.js sleep() not absolute but relative to system clock?

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, time, sleep

Programming in Node.js on my Ubuntu system, I need to set an interval timer to do certain events:

```
setInterval(function() {
    console.log(new Date());
}, 5000);
```

This executes every 5 seconds as you would expect, but as soon as you change the system clock, weird things start to happen. If I set my system clock to the past, it waits until the clock "catches" up to last time, then waits 5 seconds. If I set system time into the future, it'll continue to wait the "leftover" times in the future. Is this expected behavior from Node or a bug? I double checked in my Windows environment with Thread.Sleep() in C# and it doesn't do this. It will always wait 5 seconds and do things even if you change system clock. How do I achieve this with Node?

Comment: The difference is that while `Thread.sleep(5)` literally causes the program to suspend and then wake up after a certain amount of time (5 seconds worth of processor ticks), `setInterval(...)` sets a timer and checks periodically if 5 seconds have passed before running the function.  `setInterval` is dependent on the system clock, and `Thread.sleep` is not.

Comment: You are just stating what I observed, I understand how this happened, the question was why it happened and ways around it as this is obviously a bug or a limitation of Node and can be exploited.

Comment: If you feel this is a bug or exploit vector, you should probably create [an issue](https://github.com/joyent/node/issues) (I never had any issues with this behaviour, mostly because I don't change my system clock very often, nor can regular (non-root) users do that).